# how to find application class name?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

that required in first parameter of [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function?

there long time,I seen this information using Autoit Info Tool. But how I find it using C# it is possible?Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but it you are asking how to get the name of a class at runtime, use reflections.   Again, this may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify, applications don't have "classes". You're refering to the window class which is the base template for any window on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother?

> If lpClassName is NULL, it finds any window whose title matches the
>   lpWindowName parameter.

Just pass NULL there If you want to find a window.

Comment: it truth. today seems like a without brain day for me. Thanks!